# Adding CSS for specific CMS Page via Layout Update XML - Magento 2.4.x

Tags: magento2, layout, css, custom-layout-update

I want to add the custom css for specific CMS Page, I know we can create a new theme for it but I want to use the Layout Update XML Or by adding it to empty page layout directly.

Currently, if I add the below code and hit save, the changes get disappeared from admin and nothing get changes on frontend.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="head">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="css" xsi:type="string">css/landingpg.css</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

How to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Layout Update XML is no more useful in Magento 2.4 so the alternate solutions is just add the new file in child theme.

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/mytheme/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_page_view_selectable_cmsurl_LandingPG.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="css/landingpg.css"/>
</head>
```

Where, cmsurl is the url of CMS Page & LandingPG can be anything that will come visible under the Design -> Custom Update XML